# Swift Loops The Console is not in the right order

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

```
var letters = ["a": "Alpha", "b": "Bravo", "c": "Charlie", "d": "Delta"]

for (letter, pilotAlphabet) in letters {
    print("\(letter) stands for \(pilotAlphabet)")
}
```

This is my code on the Playgrounds. The console gives this:

```
b stands for Bravo
a stands for Alpha
d stands for Delta
c stands for Charlie
```

I wonder why this outcome is not in the order I given.

Comment: There is no order inside `Dictionary` only inside `Array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`letters` is a `Dictionary`, whose keys and values are both `String`s. A `Dictionary` is an unordered collection by definition, so when iterating through the key-value pairs of the dictionary, the ordering won't be the same as the order in which you added the values to the dictionary, nor will it be alphabetical.

If you need to display the key-value pairs in alphabetical order, you can do so by calling `sorted` on the `Dictionary` and iterating through the resulting `Array` of tuples.

```
var letters = ["a": "Alpha", "b": "Bravo", "c": "Charlie", "d": "Delta"]

for (letter, pilotAlphabet) in letters.sorted(by: {$0.key<$1.key}) {
    print("\(letter) stands for \(pilotAlphabet)")
}
```

Output:

```
a stands for Alpha
b stands for Bravo
c stands for Charlie
d stands for Delta
```

Comment: I did not know ".sorted" and thanks to you I have learnt something new! And I get the same output as the one you share.

Comment: Note that `Dictionary.sorted()` maps the dictionary to an array of tuples (in your case `(key:String, value: String)`.)

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the contents of a `Dictionary` you do so as an *unordered* collection of key-value pairs. The order is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) to be stable between mutations but otherwise unpredictable.

Comment: I have just learnt that I have to use ".sorted" I'm glad to have your answers I also learn the use of Dictionaries.